# update value in column and have a trigger update another column depending on the value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table. In this table there are three columns I am interested in creating a trigger on.

**My table - tblABC**

```
column name       data type

Id                int (primary key)
Live              bit
CompletionDate    date
CancelDate        date
```

So I would like the trigger to execute whenever the CompletionDate or CancelDate is updated.

I want the trigger to do one of two things

1) if either the CompletionDate or CancelDate columns date is changed to a date that is equal to today or less then I want the Live column to equal 0.

2) if either the CompletionDate or CancelDate columns date is changed to a date that is greater than today or NULL then I want the Live column to equal 1.

Below is my code. I am not sure if its correct also I'm not sure how this will deal with NULLS?

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_MYTRIGGER
ON  tblABC
AFTER UPDATE

update d
set d.Live = 0
from tblABC e d 
inner join inserted i on d.Id = i.Id
where i.CompletionDate <= GETDATE() or i.CancelDate <= GETDATE()

update d
set d.Live = 1
from tblABC d 
inner join inserted i on d.Id = i.Id
where i.CompletionDate > GETDATE() and i.CancelDate > GETDATE()
```

Comment: Just to check, as time moves on, would the value of this flag stay as it was when it was originally set, or would you expect it to change? (the latter being more of a computed column)

Comment: @Andrew when the record is first added to the table it would be 1 and then at some point down the line it would change to 0 and then I would it expect it to remain that way... hopefully that makes sense

Comment: If you expect that change to happen auto-magically and be accurate at all times then a computed column for the value makes more sense. If you expect it to only change when an update causes the trigger to fire, and thus it could be wrong for a period of time until an update causes the logic to run, then the trigger remains ok

Comment: @Andrew sorry I haven't come across a computed column before & why would this be better than a trigger?

Comment: The computed column (which can also be persisted) will always implement the logic each time its read, the trigger will only apply the logic when it is (by definition) triggered to run. Since your trigger requires an update, if the row is not updated after it is originally set, the value will not change for you / not be recomputed.

Comment: oh I see, that does sound better. Will google to how to create a computed column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said in your second point, if **either** of the two dates is set to greater than today **or** set to `null` then you need to set your live column to 1. Change your second update query to this.

```
update d
set d.Live = 1
from tblABC d 
inner join inserted i on d.Id = i.Id
where (i.CompletionDate > GETDATE() or i.CancelDate > GETDATE() 
or i.CompletionDate is null or i.CancelDate is null) and d.Live <> 1
```

But as suggested in the comments, a computed column seems like a better option.

**Edit** For performance optimization, you shouldn't update the rows that are already `1`. See updated query. Do the same for your first update query.